# I cannot add multiple inline images in Outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I want to add multiple images into my mail body with office.js.

I am using the following code:

```js
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(uri,
            assetName,
            { isInline: true },
            function (asyncResult) { //resolvepromise });
```

(After I have called this multiple times I insert the right html with cids in my mail body)

If I don't use `isInline`, the pictures are all added to my mail body, but they are shown in the attachment bar.

If I do use `isInline` only one of all the images in inserted right in my mail body (others are white squares with red cross in the corner).

I also tried calling `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync` after adding each attachment but that didn't help either.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using in the callback (i.e. `//resolvepromise`)?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use *'setAsync'* function to insert the images inside the body without using this '*addFileAttachmentAsync*'? it's more simple this way.

```
 var htmlContent='<img src=".."><img src="..">';
 Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
                                     htmlContent,
                                    {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html },
                                    function (asyncResult) { });
```

Comment: So how would I insert the images then? The urls I use are temporary and only valid for couple of minutes so I need the image files to be included as attachments

Comment: @Nick Exactly how I post to you above , with 'setAsync' function .You could insert html inside the body with t his function , so create your img element inside the html and then use the function simply .

Comment: The urls I use for the images are only valid for a couple of minutes, so I don't want the images to point to that, so that's why I want to add them as attachments

Comment: @Nick So you want these imeags as attachments or in the body ? or both ?

Comment: I want them in my body, but I don't want them to rely on a url. So I want them in it just like when you do a insert image from you local drive. (inline attachment)

Answer (score 0):

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
"https://i.imgur.com/tH8sYNt.png",
"test3.png", 
{asyncContext: null, isInline: true},  
function (asyncResult)  {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync( 
                    "<img src='cid:test3.png'>", 
                    { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html,
                         asyncContext: null });
}
```

The above code is working for me. On Outlook 2016 C2R, Can you provide some sample inputs into your code if it is not working? Namely what you are doing to set the body? Also provide some version information on your client. (Desktop Outlook 2016? 2013? OWA? Specific version number)

Comment: yes I am also doing it like that, for one picture it is going fine for multiple it fails:
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
"https://i.imgur.com/tH8sYNt.png",
"test3.png", 
{isInline: true},
function (asyncResult) {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
  "https://i.imgur.com/SknNBOl.jpg",
  "test4.png", 
  {isInline: true},
  function (asyncResult) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync( 
    "<img src='cid:test3.png'><img src='cid:test4.png'>", 
    { coercionType: "html",
           asyncContext: null });
    }

Comment: When I don't add an extension (like .png) the pictures do show up in my mail body, but then the receiver sees the attachments. When I do add extensions only one pictures show up in my composing mail body (others are white with red cross in corner). But in this case no attachments are shown at receivers end. this is both on Desktop Win32 Outlook 2016 and on MAC. Outlook Online it is not inserting images in both cases

Comment: It is a bug in the API in outlook desktop, and we are working on it. For now, please either leaving out extension if you prefer inline image or setting isInline to false, if attached images are acceptable. For outlook online, could you provide more details, like browser, error message, etc, since we cannot repro it. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: @Nick - Like pointed out above, this is a bug and we are actively working on it. In the meantime, you can do the following to unblock yourself:
Right after setting the first attachment, call into setBody within the callback, then within setBody's callback call addFileAttachmentAsync for your second attachment and within its callback call setBody again.
This should have you unblocked and you should be able to add multiple inline images following this pattern. Once the issue is fixed we will update the post with the same.